# call function in jquery by first event that occurs

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to run a `javascript` function by the only event so that the first event that occurs should call it and when the next event occurs it should not be called again.

so I have a function set up on 2 events but it should only be called by either of event, not the both.

Answer (score 0):

Return `false` from all handlers involved to prevent subsequent ones from firing.

This is the equivalent of calling both `e.preventDefault()` and `e.stopPropagation()`, which is to say it not only stops other event handlers from firing, it also prevents the browser's default action, eg. submitting a form.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `off()` to remove the binding once it happens.  If you were only binding on a single event, you could simply use `one()`, but since you are binding on multiple events, it would still be bound to the other event in that case.  So you have to explicitly remove it from both when one happens.

```js
function myMethod(){
  console.log('This should happen only once');
  $('#target').off('blur change', myMethod);
}

$('#target').on('blur change', myMethod);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="target" value="">
```

Optionally, you could also use a delegate to handle this.

```js
$(document.body).on('blur change', '#target:not(.ignore)', function(e){
  console.log('This should happen only once');
  $(e.target).addClass('ignore');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="target" value="">
```